# Where to put a dowloaded Python module

Tags: 12.10, python

In Ubuntu 12.10. What is the advised directory to put a downloaded python library? Should I be concerned about confusing apt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: A python module is pretty much just a simple file. Why would that confuse apt (even if you place it in say /bin)? Apt only cares with package descriptors, and anything else is pretty much ignored by it. So as long as you don't overwrite anything you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the only user on the machine that needs access to this Python module then avoid placing it anywhere outside your home directory. You can place it pretty much anywhere under your home directory and add that directory to your [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. For example, you may place it under `~/Projects/MySoftwareProject/Packages/` and then add this directory to `PYTHONPATH` whenever you work on that project. A more convenient method of doing this is to use [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/1.9.X/#what-it-does) to create isolated Python environment for different projects.

If you need to install this Python module system wide (so that multiple users may be able to use it) look for it in the standard package repository first. If you cannot find it there then look for a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) for it; maybe the developer of this module has created one. If you cannot find one, you may want to create one (it will help others). Installing it manually ought to be the last resort. :D

Having said that, if you absolutely do need to install it manually, a good place to install packages locally is [`/usr/local`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY). So, for example, this module may be placed under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.